# Julia - performance of CartesianIndices

Tags: performance, julia, benchmarking

I was digging around in the source code of `Base.IteratorsMD` and I was convinced that the implementation of `Base.nextind` for `CartesianIndex` (in `julia/base/multidimensional.jl`, see here https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/55e36cc308b66d3472990a06b2797f9f9154ea0a/base/multidimensional.jl#L142-L150 ) must be highly inefficient:

```
function Base.nextind(a::AbstractArray{<:Any,N}, i::CartesianIndex{N}) where {N}
    iter = CartesianIndices(axes(a))
    return CartesianIndex(inc(i.I, first(iter).I, last(iter).I))
end
```

I assumed that creating a new instance of `CartesianIndices(...)` in every call must be very expensive, since on my machine a call to `CartesianIndices(...)` via REPL seems to create all indices.
So I wrote the following benchmark script for an alternative implementation `mynextind`:

```
using Base.IteratorsMD

function mynextind(a::AbstractArray{<:Any,N}, i::CartesianIndex{N}) where {N}
    dims = (x.stop for x in axes(a))
    return CartesianIndex(Base.IteratorsMD.inc(i.I, CartesianIndex(ones(Int64, length(dims))...).I, CartesianIndex(dims...).I))
end

function f(func, M)
    c = CartesianIndex(1,1)
    while true
        (c = func(M, c)) == CartesianIndex(size(M)...) && break
    end
end

A = rand(100,100)

@btime f(Base.nextind, A)
@btime f(mynextind, A)
```

`Base.nextind` was several orders of magnitude faster (7μs vs 12ms) than `mynextind`. Also, `Base.nextind` doesn't seem to make any memory allocations. Now I'm trying to understand why this is the case. Does `CartesianIndices` actually create all indices or not?

Comment: I can't profess to understand what exactly is going on, but my suspicion is that through inlining the function calls, julia's complier is able to do a bunch of dead code elimination so it is actually skipping all the extra work you thought it was doing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I assumed that creating a new instance of CartesianIndices(...) in every call must be very expensive, since on my machine a call to CartesianIndices(...) via REPL seems to create all indices.

This is not valid.

When you print `CartesianIndices(...)` in REPL, all the elements will be printed. But this doesn't mean that it will create all the indices.

As you can see in the source code of the struct of `CartesianIndices` here:
https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/64d8ca49122609d1c10c72a96d1711b95346980a/base/multidimensional.jl#L248

When you create an instance like `CartesianIndices(axes(A))`, only the axes are stored. The reason that you saw all indices are printed is that the `CartesianIndices` is an `AbstractArray`. And it also implements the `getindex` methods. So when you type `CartesianIndices(axes(A))`, all the indices are calculated on demand.

And you can see more discussions about CartesianIndices here: https://discourse.julialang.org/t/psa-replacement-of-ind2sub-sub2ind-in-julia-0-7/14666

Comment: Perhaps "on demand" would be a clearer phrase than "in real-time", if I'm understanding your meaning correctly that using `CartesianIndices(axes(A))` in the REPL does trigger this demand, but in other cases lazy evaluation isn't triggered.

Comment: Thanks for the answer & reference! So do I understand correctly that AbstractArrays may behave differently in compiled code vs the REPL? What exactly is it that triggers the real-time / on demand calculation of all the cartesian indices in the REPL?

Comment: @untergam: I don't know the Julia language, but presumably it's the fact that the REPL *prints* the result.  i.e. triggering demand for all the lazily-evaluated things.  If you used `CartesianIndices` as part of a larger expression in the REPL, that wouldn't trigger the cost.

Comment: @untergam I think the REPL will call `show` or some functions similar to print the struct. And then it is triggered.